# Find more than one string with underscore.js _.where function

Tags: underscore.js

lets say that I have this array of objects.

```
var initialData = [{Title:"Hat",Price:49.95},
                   {Title:"Pants",Price:78.25},                 
                  {Title:"Shirt",Price:12.34}];
```

I know that I can find which objects have the Title = "Hat" using the _.where function.

```
// underscore method
console.log( _.where(initialData, {Title:"Hat"}));
```

But what if I want to look for all the object that contain Title = "Hat" or "Shirt"?
Is possible to do it with the same _.where function?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You should use `_.filter` in this case.

Answer (score 7):

Thanks Simon. I did what you suggested, and the code below is working.

```
var initialData = [{Title:"Hat",Price:49.95},
                   {Title:"Pants",Price:78.25},                 
                  {Title:"Shirt",Price:12.34}];

var match=['Hat', 'Shirt'];

//underscore method
console.log( _.filter(initialData, function(num){ return _.contains(match,num.Title) }));
```

Thanks